# Hook to render all active Facet

Tags: 7, hooks, search

Is there a possible hook or something else that can be written to display all the current active facet link i.e the selected facet. i want to display to the user in breadcrumb format  all the facet they have selected and give them the option to remove it 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bock for this.

You can create/configure the block from Configuration->Search and Metadata->Current Search block (admin/config/search/current_search)

Create a new Search Block and choose a type: Active Items. In pattern enter from tokens below: [facetapi_active:active-value]
Then go to your blocks page and activate your new block.

See the screenshot how my settings look like.

[image: Settings for Current Search Block]

Comment: do you have any ideas on how to add clear all